# Will swapping receiver polarity on a spiral antenna change right hand to left hand polarization?

Tags: antenna, polarization, circular-polarization

I'm evaluating a helix antenna, and wanted to try out a reverse circular polarization than it's designed for.  I do know that it's balanced and has no other components that would preclude polarity reversal, so as long as I take care for grounding issues around the connector I won't damage the receiver or antenna.

Am I correct in thinking that simply reversing the connection to the receiver will also reverse the circular polarization of the antenna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by reversing connection? If you just swap the ground and center wire of the feeding coaxial you create 180 phase shift, not change the polarization.

The polarization of a helix antenna is determined by the rotation direction of the helix (right handed helix radiates right handed circular polarization). If you want to change the helix designed for RHCP to radiate LHCP, you must re-wire the entire helix. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helical_antenna

Answer (score 3):

No. Reversing the conductors of the feed line produces a 180° phase shift (which is generally completely irrelevant) and has no effect on polarization.

One way you could reverse the polarization without modifying the antenna would be to reflect the signal once.